# How Can I test a basic Bearer Strategy for Passport.js using Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, postman

I'm trying to grasp passport at the moment, particularly how to Authenticate a Restful api and I am a little unsure how to test it what I have

I have the following BearerStrategy:

```
var BearerStrategy = new Bearer({
  },
  function(token, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {

      findByToken(token, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    });
  }
);
```

where findByToken is:

```
var api_users = [
    { id: 1, username: 'bob', token: '123456789', email: 'bob@example.com' }
  , { id: 2, username: 'joe', token: 'abcdefghi', email: 'joe@example.com' }
];
function findByToken(token, fn) {
  for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
    var user = api_users[i];
    if (user.token === token) {
      return fn(null, user);
    }
  }
  return fn(null, null);
}
```

and I then Have the following route:

```
app.get('/api', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false}), function (request, response){
    response.send('BAM! you got a response');
});
```

I have tried testing in postman but and I get `Unauthorized` but I am unsure how to test this for success. The above code is not all mine, it is the simplest solution I could piece together from a few snippets I found online.

In Post man I have the options: Normal, Basic Auth which requires the params `username and Password`

Digest Auth which look's for params `Username, Realm, Password, Nonce, Algorithm, qop, Nonce count, Client nonce, Opaque`

OAuth 1.0 which looks for the params `Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Token, Token Secret, Signature Method, Timestamp,Nonce, Version, Realm, Add params to header ,Auto add parameters`

This is all new to me and I have tried Googling how to test. Any Guidance anyone can offer would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out What I was trying to do was use a `token` param when I needed a `access_token`

Here's a screen shot in case anyone needs to know how to test

[image]

Comment: Thats great, but this is the old postman version... It was easy back then using `normal` authentication but right now theres no such thing in the new potman chrome app.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone is looking for a solution on the later postman version. You can setup your postman to include the key "Authorization" and its value will be "Bearer XXXXX" Where XXX is the access_token value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot man. :-) I was banging my head why the hell postman is not sending auth token....